# why the postgersql kubernetes statefulset did not claim the PVC

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

Today I want to change the PostgreSQL statefulset PVC name, to my surprise, I did not found any clain about the PVC in the kubernetes deployment define, this is the kubernetes deployment define of PostgreSQL:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql
  namespace: reddwarf-storage
  uid: 787a18c8-f6fb-4deb-bb07-3c3d123cf6f9
  resourceVersion: '21931453'
  generation: 30
  creationTimestamp: '2021-08-05T05:29:03Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: reddwarf-postgresql
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
    helm.sh/chart: postgresql-10.9.1
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"StatefulSet","metadata":{"annotations":{"meta.helm.sh/release-name":"reddwarf-postgresql","meta.helm.sh/release-namespace":"reddwarf-storage"},"creationTimestamp":"2021-08-05T05:29:03Z","generation":12,"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"primary","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"reddwarf-postgresql","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","app.kubernetes.io/name":"postgresql","helm.sh/chart":"postgresql-10.9.1"},"managedFields":[{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:annotations":{".":{},"f:meta.helm.sh/release-name":{},"f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace":{}},"f:labels":{".":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/component":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/instance":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/name":{},"f:helm.sh/chart":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:podManagementPolicy":{},"f:replicas":{},"f:revisionHistoryLimit":{},"f:selector":{},"f:serviceName":{},"f:template":{"f:metadata":{"f:labels":{".":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/component":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/instance":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/name":{},"f:helm.sh/chart":{},"f:role":{}},"f:name":{}},"f:spec":{"f:affinity":{".":{},"f:podAntiAffinity":{".":{},"f:preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":{}}},"f:automountServiceAccountToken":{},"f:containers":{"k:{\"name\":\"reddwarf-postgresql\"}":{".":{},"f:env":{".":{},"k:{\"name\":\"BITNAMI_DEBUG\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"PGDATA\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_LDAP\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_TLS\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_LOG_CONNECTIONS\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_LOG_DISCONNECTIONS\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_LOG_HOSTNAME\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_PGAUDIT_LOG_CATALOG\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRESQL_VOLUME_DIR\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRES_PASSWORD\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:valueFrom":{".":{},"f:secretKeyRef":{".":{},"f:key":{},"f:name":{}}}},"k:{\"name\":\"POSTGRES_USER\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}}},"f:imagePullPolicy":{},"f:livenessProbe":{".":{},"f:exec":{".":{},"f:command":{}},"f:failureThreshold":{},"f:initialDelaySeconds":{},"f:periodSeconds":{},"f:successThreshold":{},"f:timeoutSeconds":{}},"f:name":{},"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"containerPort\":5432,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}}},"f:readinessProbe":{".":{},"f:exec":{".":{},"f:command":{}},"f:failureThreshold":{},"f:initialDelaySeconds":{},"f:periodSeconds":{},"f:successThreshold":{},"f:timeoutSeconds":{}},"f:resources":{".":{},"f:requests":{".":{},"f:cpu":{},"f:memory":{}}},"f:securityContext":{".":{},"f:runAsUser":{}},"f:terminationMessagePath":{},"f:terminationMessagePolicy":{},"f:volumeMounts":{".":{},"k:{\"mountPath\":\"/bitnami/postgresql\"}":{".":{},"f:mountPath":{},"f:name":{}},"k:{\"mountPath\":\"/dev/shm\"}":{".":{},"f:mountPath":{},"f:name":{}}}}},"f:dnsPolicy":{},"f:restartPolicy":{},"f:schedulerName":{},"f:securityContext":{".":{},"f:fsGroup":{}},"f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds":{},"f:volumes":{".":{},"k:{\"name\":\"dshm\"}":{".":{},"f:emptyDir":{".":{},"f:medium":{}},"f:name":{}}}}},"f:updateStrategy":{"f:type":{}},"f:volumeClaimTemplates":{}}},"manager":"Go-http-client","operation":"Update","time":"2021-08-05T05:29:03Z"},{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:spec":{"f:template":{"f:spec":{"f:containers":{"k:{\"name\":\"reddwarf-postgresql\"}":{"f:image":{}}}}}}},"manager":"kubectl-client-side-apply","operation":"Update","time":"2021-08-10T16:50:45Z"},{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:annotations":{"f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:template":{"f:spec":{"f:containers":{"k:{\"name\":\"reddwarf-postgresql\"}":{"f:args":{}}}}}}},"manager":"kubectl","operation":"Update","time":"2021-08-11T01:46:21Z"},{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:status":{"f:collisionCount":{},"f:currentReplicas":{},"f:currentRevision":{},"f:observedGeneration":{},"f:replicas":{},"f:updateRevision":{},"f:updatedReplicas":{}}},"manager":"kube-controller-manager","operation":"Update","time":"2021-08-11T02:24:07Z"}],"name":"reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql","namespace":"reddwarf-storage","selfLink":"/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/reddwarf-storage/statefulsets/reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql","uid":"787a18c8-f6fb-4deb-bb07-3c3d123cf6f9"},"spec":{"podManagementPolicy":"OrderedReady","replicas":1,"revisionHistoryLimit":10,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"reddwarf-postgresql","app.kubernetes.io/name":"postgresql","role":"primary"}},"serviceName":"reddwarf-postgresql-headless","template":{"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"primary","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"reddwarf-postgresql","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","app.kubernetes.io/name":"postgresql","helm.sh/chart":"postgresql-10.9.1","role":"primary"},"name":"reddwarf-postgresql"},"spec":{"affinity":{"podAntiAffinity":{"preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":[{"podAffinityTerm":{"labelSelector":{"matchLabels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"primary","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"reddwarf-postgresql","app.kubernetes.io/name":"postgresql"}},"namespaces":["reddwarf-storage"],"topologyKey":"kubernetes.io/hostname"},"weight":1}]}},"automountServiceAccountToken":false,"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"BITNAMI_DEBUG","value":"false"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER","value":"5432"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_VOLUME_DIR","value":"/bitnami/postgresql"},{"name":"PGDATA","value":"/bitnami/postgresql/data"},{"name":"POSTGRES_USER","value":"postgres"},{"name":"POSTGRES_PASSWORD","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"postgresql-password","name":"reddwarf-postgresql"}}},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_LDAP","value":"no"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_TLS","value":"no"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_LOG_HOSTNAME","value":"false"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_LOG_CONNECTIONS","value":"false"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_LOG_DISCONNECTIONS","value":"false"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_PGAUDIT_LOG_CATALOG","value":"off"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES","value":"error"},{"name":"POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES","value":"pgaudit"}],"image":"docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:13.3.0-debian-10-r75","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","livenessProbe":{"exec":{"command":["/bin/sh","-c","exec
      pg_isready -U \"postgres\" -h 127.0.0.1 -p
      5432"]},"failureThreshold":6,"initialDelaySeconds":30,"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":5},"name":"reddwarf-postgresql","ports":[{"containerPort":5432,"name":"tcp-postgresql","protocol":"TCP"}],"readinessProbe":{"exec":{"command":["/bin/sh","-c","-e","exec
      pg_isready -U \"postgres\" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432\n[ -f
      /opt/bitnami/postgresql/tmp/.initialized ] || [ -f
      /bitnami/postgresql/.initialized
      ]\n"]},"failureThreshold":6,"initialDelaySeconds":5,"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":5},"resources":{"requests":{"cpu":"250m","memory":"256Mi"}},"securityContext":{"runAsUser":1001},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/dev/shm","name":"dshm"},{"mountPath":"/bitnami/postgresql","name":"data"}]}],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","restartPolicy":"Always","schedulerName":"default-scheduler","securityContext":{"fsGroup":1001},"terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30,"volumes":[{"emptyDir":{"medium":"Memory"},"name":"dshm"}]}},"updateStrategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate"},"volumeClaimTemplates":[{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"name":"data"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"8Gi"}},"volumeMode":"Filesystem"},"status":{"phase":"Pending"}}]}}
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: reddwarf-postgresql
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: reddwarf-storage
  managedFields:
    - manager: Go-http-client
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2021-08-05T05:29:03Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-name': {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/component': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
            'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:podManagementPolicy': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:revisionHistoryLimit': {}
          'f:selector': {}
          'f:serviceName': {}
          'f:template':
            'f:metadata':
              'f:labels':
                .: {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/component': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
                'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
                'f:role': {}
              'f:name': {}
            'f:spec':
              'f:affinity':
                .: {}
                'f:podAntiAffinity':
                  .: {}
                  'f:preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution': {}
              'f:automountServiceAccountToken': {}
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"reddwarf-postgresql"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:env':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"name":"BITNAMI_DEBUG"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"PGDATA"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_LDAP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_TLS"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_LOG_CONNECTIONS"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_LOG_DISCONNECTIONS"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_LOG_HOSTNAME"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_PGAUDIT_LOG_CATALOG"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRESQL_VOLUME_DIR"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRES_PASSWORD"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef':
                          .: {}
                          'f:key': {}
                          'f:name': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POSTGRES_USER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                  'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
                  'f:livenessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:exec':
                      .: {}
                      'f:command': {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:ports':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":5432,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                  'f:readinessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:exec':
                      .: {}
                      'f:command': {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
                  'f:resources':
                    .: {}
                    'f:requests':
                      .: {}
                      'f:cpu': {}
                      'f:memory': {}
                  'f:securityContext':
                    .: {}
                    'f:runAsUser': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
                  'f:volumeMounts':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"mountPath":"/bitnami/postgresql"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:mountPath': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                    'k:{"mountPath":"/dev/shm"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:mountPath': {}
                      'f:name': {}
              'f:dnsPolicy': {}
              'f:restartPolicy': {}
              'f:schedulerName': {}
              'f:securityContext':
                .: {}
                'f:fsGroup': {}
              'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
              'f:volumes':
                .: {}
                'k:{"name":"dshm"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:emptyDir':
                    .: {}
                    'f:medium': {}
                  'f:name': {}
          'f:updateStrategy':
            'f:type': {}
          'f:volumeClaimTemplates': {}
    - manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2021-08-10T16:50:45Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:spec':
          'f:template':
            'f:spec':
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"reddwarf-postgresql"}':
                  'f:image': {}
    - manager: kubectl
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2021-08-11T02:29:20Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            'f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration': {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2021-11-27T03:07:58Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          'f:collisionCount': {}
          'f:currentRevision': {}
          'f:observedGeneration': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:updateRevision': {}
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/reddwarf-storage/statefulsets/reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql
status:
  observedGeneration: 30
  replicas: 0
  currentRevision: reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-5695cb9676
  updateRevision: reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-5695cb9676
  collisionCount: 0
spec:
  replicas: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: reddwarf-postgresql
      app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
      role: primary
  template:
    metadata:
      name: reddwarf-postgresql
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: reddwarf-postgresql
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
        helm.sh/chart: postgresql-10.9.1
        role: primary
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
      containers:
        - name: reddwarf-postgresql
          image: 'docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:13.3.0-debian-10-r75'
          ports:
            - name: tcp-postgresql
              containerPort: 5432
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
              value: 'false'
            - name: POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER
              value: '5432'
            - name: POSTGRESQL_VOLUME_DIR
              value: /bitnami/postgresql
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /bitnami/postgresql/data
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: reddwarf-postgresql
                  key: postgresql-password
            - name: POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_LDAP
              value: 'no'
            - name: POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_TLS
              value: 'no'
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_HOSTNAME
              value: 'false'
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_CONNECTIONS
              value: 'false'
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_DISCONNECTIONS
              value: 'false'
            - name: POSTGRESQL_PGAUDIT_LOG_CATALOG
              value: 'off'
            - name: POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES
              value: error
            - name: POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES
              value: pgaudit
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: dshm
              mountPath: /dev/shm
            - name: data
              mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 6
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - '-e'
                - >
                  exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432

                  [ -f /opt/bitnami/postgresql/tmp/.initialized ] || [ -f
                  /bitnami/postgresql/.initialized ]
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 6
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1001
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 1
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance: reddwarf-postgresql
                    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
                namespaces:
                  - reddwarf-storage
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: data
        creationTimestamp: null
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 8Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
      status:
        phase: Pending
  serviceName: reddwarf-postgresql-headless
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
```

this statefulset bind the PVC named `data-reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-0` right now, but I did not found the PVC define in this statefulset yaml. where is the PVC bind define? what should I do to change the PVC to bind to a new one? I install this PostgreSQL into kubernetes from helm chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pvc thats gets created as a part of statefulset will have a name which is an amalgamation of 3 components joined by `-` :

1. Name defined in the `volumeClaimTemplates` section `data`
2. Name of the `statefulset` in the metadata section which is `reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql`
3. Its replica number , if it is first replica then it would be `0`

So finally the name of the pvc that gets created when you create this statefulset is
`data-reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-0`.which is the pvc name that you also seeing in your setup.

please note when you delete the statefulset , pvc does not deleted automatically we need to pvc separately. When you recreate/scaleup the stateful set and if the pvc which matches above naming convention& spec does not exists then it will create a pvc.

[From kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id)